# Consuming asp.net web.api json not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm trying to consume my web api which returns JSON format from my asp.net mvc web application. As my JSON format has root node (the way i filled with oledb dataset). I'm keep getting the following error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[FileAttributes]' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'SearchData', line 1, position
>   14.

Here is the code sample

```
string Baseurl = "http://localhost:62602/";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/FileSearch/?searchTerm=" + searchTerm );
if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var fsResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    List<FileAttributes> fileAttribultes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FileAttributes>>(fsResponse);
}
```

And then following some ideas, I used `JSON.Parse` and `SelectToken` to remove root node, but this time the `List<FileAttributes>` returns data but with null values

```
JToken jtok = JObject.Parse(fsResponse).SelectToken("SearchData");
List<FileAttributes> fileAttribultes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FileAttributes>>(fsResponse);
```

Here is my FileAttributes class

```
public class FileAttributes
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
 }
```

I appreciate if anyone check whats wrong in the deserialization of JSON part with root node and whats the right way to do it?

Copied from POSTMAN output

```
{ "SearchData": [ { "SYSTEM.NAME": "FILE NAME 1" , "SYSTEM.HEADER": "HEADER 1", "SYSTEM.TITLE": "TITLE 1", }, { "SYSTEM.NAME": "FILE NAME 1" , "SYSTEM.HEADER": "HEADER 1", "SYSTEM.TITLE": "TITLE 1", }, { "SYSTEM.NAME": "FILE NAME 1" , "SYSTEM.HEADER": "HEADER 1", "SYSTEM.TITLE": "TITLE 1", }] }
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like? the error message actually tells you what you need to do to solve the problem.

Comment: Oops Sorry, forgot to mention JSON sample. Copied from POSTMAN output

`{
    "SearchData": [
        {
            "SYSTEM.NAME": "FILE NAME 1" ,
            "SYSTEM.HEADER": "HEADER 1",
            "SYSTEM.TITLE": "TITLE 1",
          
        },
    {
            "SYSTEM.NAME": "FILE NAME 1" ,
            "SYSTEM.HEADER": "HEADER 1",
            "SYSTEM.TITLE": "TITLE 1",
          
        },
  {
            "SYSTEM.NAME": "FILE NAME 1" ,
            "SYSTEM.HEADER": "HEADER 1",
            "SYSTEM.TITLE": "TITLE 1",
          
        }]
}`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the JSON the object model needs to be updated to match. Which also need to include `JsonProperty` attribute to match up the JSON keys to the properties of the class.

```
public class FileAttributes {
    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.HEADER")]
    public string Header { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("SYSTEM.TITLE")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject {
    public IList<FileAttributes> SearchData { get; set; }
}
```

Then update the call to the service accordingly

```
string Baseurl = "http://localhost:62602/";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
var response = await client.GetAsync("api/FileSearch/?searchTerm=" + searchTerm );
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var fileAttribultes = result.SearchData; 
    //...
}
```